# Java search method between objects using scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to make a program in java oop in which I create some persons in the main (every person has a name, an age, a status: employed or not).

I want to search these persons by name and display all the details.

For example if a have a person named John and I find it by name, I want to list all the details (status, age and so on).

I tried to implement this method in Person class.
I don t know if is better to create a map which contains all the persons and the name and then to search in it.

Below is my code:

Person CLASS:

```
package app;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Person extends Employed {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
private String name;
private int age;
private int kids;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public int getKids() {
    return kids;
}

public void setKids(int kids) {
    this.kids = kids;
}

public Person(){
        System.out.println("************************************************************");
}

public void displayPerson(){
    if(super.getPeriod()==0 && super.getUnemploymentBenefit()==0){
        System.out.println(name + " is " + age + " years old, has " + kids + " kids and is employed" + "\nWorking Place: " + super.getWorkingPlace() 
                            + "\nSallary: " + df.format(super.getSallary()) + " EUR per year" + "\nWorking Time: " + super.getHours() + " hours per day");
    }else 
        System.out.println(name + " is " + age + " years old, has " + kids + " kids and is unemployed" +"\nUnemployment Time: " + Math.round(super.getPeriod()) 
                            + "\nUnemployment Benefit: " + df.format(super.getUnemploymentBenefit()) + " EUR per year");        
}




public void searchMethod(){
   System.out.println("Are you looking for someone?");
   String s = scan.nextLine();

   if(s==name) {
       System.out.println("Here are all the details about the person you are looking for: ");
   }
}

}
```

Employed CLASS:

```
package app;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class Employed extends Unemployed {
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.000");

private String WorkingPlace;
private double sallary;
private double hours;

public String getWorkingPlace() {
    return WorkingPlace;
}

public void setWorkingPlace(String WorkingPlace) {
    this.WorkingPlace = WorkingPlace;
}

public double getSallary() {
    return sallary;
}

public void setSallary(double sallary) {
    this.sallary = sallary;
}

public double getHours() {
    return hours;
}

public void setHours(double hours) {
    this.hours = hours;
}

}
```

Unemployeed CLASS:

```
package app;

public class Unemployed{

private double period;
private double UnemploymentBenefit;

public double getPeriod() {
    return period;
}

public void setPeriod(double period) {
    this.period = period;
}

public double getUnemploymentBenefit() {
    return UnemploymentBenefit;
}

public void setUnemploymentBenefit(double UnemploymentBenefit) {
    this.UnemploymentBenefit = UnemploymentBenefit;
}

}
```

Program CLASS:

```
package app;
public class Program extends Person{

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Person p1 = new Person();
    p1.setName("John Doe");
    p1.setAge(47);
    p1.setKids(3);
    p1.setWorkingPlace("IKEA");
    p1.setSallary(12.500);
    p1.setHours(12.5);
    p1.displayPerson();
    p1.searchMethod();

    Person p2 = new Person();
    p2.setName("Snow Tiffany");
    p2.setAge(27);
    p2.setKids(0);
    p2.setPeriod(15.9);
    p2.setUnemploymentBenefit(7.000);
    p2.displayPerson();







}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should add a construtor.

Then you can create an object from class Person like this:

```
 Person p1 = new Person("John Doe", 47,3, "IKEA", 12.500, 12.5);

 String personInfo = p1.get(..) + p1.get(..);

 System.out.println(personInfo);
```

Your code is a bit desorganized. Java classes should have constructors. Variables, in general, starts with lowerCase character.

Comment: Thx for your advices. I will try to make it with constructors.